How do I find the correct selenium locator for search input box
I am trying to automate searching food on swiggy but I am getting error when I try to automate the search inputbox. I am using SelectorsHub to find the locators but still I am facing issues. I am getting the following output in my terminal
code snippet:
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://google.com')
browser.maximize_window()

search = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='APjFqb']")
search.send_keys("Swiggy")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

site = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Swiggy")
site.click()

search_btn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Search']")
search_btn.click()

search_food = (browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class*="SearchButton"]'))
search_food.click()

time.sleep(10)

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@placeholder='Search for restaurants and food']"}
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.107); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713927032+63090]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713892C82]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71372EC65]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71377499D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713774ADC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7137B5B37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71379701F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7137B3412]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713796D83]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7137683A8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713769441]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713D225AD+4238317]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713D5F70D+4488525]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713D579EF+4456495]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713A00576+953270]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71389E54F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713899224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71389935B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713889B94]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC9DBB257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC9F24AA48+40]


//input[@placeholder='Search for restaurants and food']

Above XPath expression is incorrect. It does not locate any element. You need to:

First click on the "Search for restaurant and food" element using following XPath expression - //div[text()='Search for restaurant and food']
Now you will notice text box "Search for Dishes and Restaurants" gets enabled, send any text of your choice into the textbox using send_keys(). For example send text "Biryani"
Use following XPath expression- //div[contains(@class,'style__ItemContainer')]//button[1]//img to select the first item in the search dropdown. If you want the second item just change //button[1] to //button[2], and for third item //button[3] and so on.

Refer the working code below:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.swiggy.com/city/bangalore")
# Create an explicit wait object with wait time of 10s
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Search for restaurant and food']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search for Dishes and Restaurants']"))).send_keys("Biryani")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'style__ItemContainer')]//button[1]//img"))).click()
time.sleep(10)

Result:

UPDATE: Three issues:

By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class*="SearchButton"]' - this selector is incorrect, does not locate any element.
When https://google.com is launched, Accept/Reject cookies pop-up is shown, you need to get rid of it before proceeding with next line of code
Use Selenium's waits

Refer the below code where above 3 issues are taken care:
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://google.com')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Accept all']").click()
search = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='APjFqb']")
search.send_keys("Swiggy")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

site = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Swiggy")
site.click()

search_btn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Search']")
search_btn.click()

search_food = (browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search for restaurants and food']"))
search_food.click()
time.sleep(10)


Some explanation of what you added, why you added it, what it does, etc. would be really helpful to others.

Advise taken and explanation added.

Could you tell me what wrong am I doing in my code ? Thank You for your help!

Check the updated answer and let me know the status.

Based on the HTML, that wasn't the correct selector:

You could use 'button[class*="SearchButton"]' as a CSS Selector to click on the search field. Then you can use 'input[placeholder*="Search"]' as a CSS Selector to type into the search field. Then use "//button[contains(., 'Tofu Wrap')]" as an XPath to click on a search result containing "Tofu Wrap".
(Note that the input field itself does not exist until after clicking on the button.)
Here's a simplified https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase script (pip install seleniumbase) that does that. (Autodetects selectors and has smart-waiting.)
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB() as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.swiggy.com/city/delhi/")
    sb.click('button[class*="SearchButton"]')
    sb.type('input[placeholder*="Search"]', "Tofu Wrap")
    sb.click("//button[contains(., 'Tofu Wrap')]")
        
    breakpoint()

(Type c and press Enter to continue from the breakpoint().)

I tried using the CSS selector locator that you suggested, I am still getting error. Could you check the snippet ? I have edited the question. Thank you for your response.

Did you run the full script? Which line gave you an issue?

Your script is working absolutely fine! Could you check my script and what I am doing wrong there ? I have updated the snippet.

Looks like you're not using the same selectors that I used, in the order that I used them. I went directly to "https://www.swiggy.com/city/delhi/", then clicked 'button[class*="SearchButton"]', then typed "Tofu Wrap" into 'input[placeholder*="Search"]', and finally clicked "//button[contains(., 'Tofu Wrap')]". First two were CSS Selectors. The last was an XPath.
